# Golang: convert struct to embedded at offset 0 struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, embedding

I have some different structs like `Big` with `Small` embedded at offset 0. 
How can I access `Small`'s structure fields from code, that doesn't know anything about `Big` type, but it is known that `Small` is at offset 0?

```
type Small struct {
    val int
}

type Big struct {
    Small
    bigval int
}

var v interface{} = Big{}
// here i only know about 'Small' struct and i know that it is at the begining of variable
v.(Small).val // compile error
```

It seems that compiler is theoretically able to operate such expression, because it knows that `Big` type has `Small` type embedded at offset 0. Is there any way to do such things (maybe with `unsafe.Pointer`)?

Comment: Ignore - didn't real question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While answer with reflection is working but it has performance penalties and is not idiomatic to Go.

I believe you should use interface. Like this

https://play.golang.org/p/OG1MPHjDlQ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MySmall interface {
    SmallVal() int
}

type Small struct {
    val int
}

func (v Small) SmallVal() int {
    return v.val
}

type Big struct {
    Small
    bigval int
}

func main() {
    var v interface{} = Big{Small{val: 3}, 4}
    fmt.Printf("Small val: %v", v.(MySmall).SmallVal())
}
```

Output:

```
Small val: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) whenever possible. The above task can be done using reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package):

```
var v interface{} = Big{Small{1}, 2}

rf := reflect.ValueOf(v)
s := rf.FieldByName("Small").Interface()

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s.(Small).val)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/10WOK0nbBT)):

```
main.Small{val:1}
1
```

**Notes:**

This works for any field, not just the first one (at "offset 0"). This also works for named fields too, not just for embedded fields. This doesn't work for unexported fields though.

Comment: why not just to cast to Big and then take v.val or v.Small.val?

Reflection is overkill here, is not it?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok Asker wants a way where we don't know about `Big`. Converting or extracting a value of type `Big` does not qualify for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Small struct {
    val int
}

type Big struct {
    Small
    bigval int
}

func main() {
    var v = Big{Small{10},200}
    print(v.val)
}
```

Comment: But asker's `v` variable is of type `interface{}`, yours is of type `Big`.